# Сортировка в Jquery по условию

Tags: html, jquery

Есть выпадающий список, в некоторых данных списка есть на конце слова (не действует в 2019).

Помогите осуществить скрипт, чтобы где встречаются в конце слова (не действует в 2019) уходило вниз списка.

Т.е. те которые верхние сортировались также как и первоначально по value, и далее шли сортировкой по value те которые с  (не действует в 2019)

**JSP**

```
  <form:label path="moId"><spring:message code="label.mo" /></form:label>
    <form:select path="moId">
    <form:option value="0" label=" " />
    <form:options items="${moList}"/>
    </form:select>

<script>
"Предлагаемый скрипт"               
</script>
```

HTML

```
<select id="moId" name="moId">
<option value="0" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="1">0001 «ГН»</option>
<option value="2">0002 КМГ ВИЖУ (не действует в 2019)</option>
<option value="3">0003 НС «ГН»</option>
</select>
```

Хотелось бы видеть так
HTML

```
<select id="moId" name="moId">
<option value="0" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="1">0001 «ГН»</option>
<option value="3">0003 НС «ГН»</option>
<option value="2">0002 КМГ ВИЖУ (не действует в 2019)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Фактический дубликат вопроса [Сортировка файла txt в JAVA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1013832/%d0%a1%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-txt-%d0%b2-java). И решение такое же - использовать Array.Sort со своим компаратором.

Comment: Планировалась сортировка на Java,  переиграл на jquery

Comment: Суть от этого не поменялась, использовать Array.sort со своим компаратором.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример решения, на которое вам указывали в комментариях:

```js
$(function () {
  var sel = $("#moId"), opts = $("#moId option");
  opts.sort(function (a, b) {
    var re = /\(не действует в 2019\)$/;
      if (re.test(a.textContent)) {
        if (!re.test(a.textContent)) return 1;
      } else {
        if (re.test(b.textContent)) return -1;
      }
      return 0;
  });
  $.each(opts, function (k, v) {
    sel.append(v);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="moId" name="moId">
<option value="0" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="1">0001 «ГН»</option>
<option value="2">0002 КМГ ВИЖУ (не действует в 2019)</option>
<option value="3">0003 НС «ГН»</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает но почему-то-то в ошибка в синтаксисе ругается на "=>". Syntax error on token ">", invalid FunctionExpressionHeader

Comment: @wq55, изменил ответ - переписал стрелочные ф-ции на обычные

Comment: Jigius, Спасибо